# What is the calendar system in Camor?

Tags: gentlemen-bastards

What's the calendar system in Camor? Are "years" actually months? Or do they rename the year every month?

> It was the summer of the **Seventy-seventh Year of Gandolo**, Father of Opportunities, Lord of Coin and Commerce
>   <sub>*Lies of Locke Lamora - Prologue*</sub>

> The **Seventy-seventh Year of Gandolo** became the **Seventy-seventh Year of Morgante**, the City Father, Lord of Noose and Trowel.
>   <sub>*Lies of Locke Lamora - Prologue*</sub>

> But the **Seventy-seventh Year of Morgante** became the **Seventy-seventh Year of Sendovani**
>   <sub>*Lies of Locke Lamora - Prologue*</sub>

> It was the month of Saris in the **Seventy-seventh Year of Iono**, the end of an unusually dry and cool autumn.
>   <sub>*Lies of Locke Lamora - Interlude*</sub>

> “I have Meraggio’s Directory for the current year, **Seventy-eighth Year of Aza Guilla**, and yet…Tal Verrar…there is no listing for a West Iron Sea Mercantile Combine.”
>   <sub>*Lies of Locke Lamora - Chapter 13*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So what's the deal here? Is "the seventy-seventh year" the same year or multiple years?

Comment: It looks like "years" are actual years (since there are separate references to months and seasons) and there's a longer cycle that the count refers to.

Comment: http://camorr.wikia.com/wiki/Therin_Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the wiki article on the subject of the [Therin Calendar](http://camorr.wikia.com/wiki/Therin_Calendar)

> The Therin calendar is somewhat unusual in that, instead of numbering
> years sequentially by adding 1 to each passing year, it proceeds in 12
> year cycles, with each god of The Twelve having a year named for them
> in each cycle. So instead of year 1 being followed by year 2, we get
> the 77th year of Gandolo being followed by the 77th year of Morgante.
> Assuming this has been consistent from the beginning, the Therin
> calendar has been in place for more than 900 years.

It's noted that this isn't depicted consistently, possibly because the order of the gods changes periodically, but in reality probably just due to author error.

---

As to the question of months, there are at least seven mentioned in the texts;

- Tirastim (in spring)
- Parthis (in early summer)
- Festal (late summer)
- Saris (at the end of autumn)
- Marinel (early winter)
- Aurim (in winter)
- Tathris (unknown)

There are at least 25 days per 'month', with each 'day' being comprised of 24 'hours'. We also learn that there are four 'seasons' (Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter) each roughly comprising of three months.

It would appear that aside from the names being changed, their annual calendar roughly corresponds to our own.